# How to do Dynamic sortBy in F# LINQ to SQL

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

Is there a way to do dynamic sorting - ala dyanmic LINQ in C# - when using F# LINQ to SQL query expressions. In particular I am looking to do the following,

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open System.Data.Linq.SqlClient
open System.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type schema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE;InitialCatalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;">

let db = schema.GetDataContext()
query {
  for student in db.Student do
    sortBy "Name"  //provide column name as string rather than expr
    select student
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DynamicLinq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs) is implemented with Extension methods, those should work in F# 3.0, so why not just use DynamicLinq like you would in C#?

```
open System.Linq.Dynamic
```

...

```
let db = schema.GetDataContext()
db.Student.OrderBy("Name")
```